# jquery show two dropdowns

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have one search box. Onclick of that search box i have to display dropdown as  Bangalore,chennai,Hyderabad. Then on click of bangalore i need to hide first dropdown and display dropdown with  marthahalli,koramangala .

As soon as i click on Bangalore , the placeholder should change as bangalore and the other dropdown with marthahalli ,koramangala should display.

can anyone suggest me on this.
Here is a code of dropdowns how iam displaying.

```
<div>
<a>
    <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
</a>
<ul class="dropdown" id="dropdownhide">
    <li>
        <a>
           <span id="bangdropdown">Bangalore</span>
        </a>
    </li>
     <li>
         <a>
             <span>Chennai</span>
         </a>
     </li>
      <li>
          <a>
             <span>Hyderabad</span>
          </a>
      </li>
 </ul>
<ul class="menu" id="menu">
     <li>
        <a>
           <span>marthahalli</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>
           <span>koramangala</span>
        </a>
    </li>   
</ul>

</div>
```

Here is jquery code,

```
$('#bangdropdown').click(function(){
    $('#placeholderchange').attr('placeholder' , 'Bangalore');
    $('#dropdownhide').hide();
    $('#menu').show();  
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the javascript source of what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Please check the edition, included jquery code

Comment: The thing you are trying to achieve is called `cascading` you need to show more code of jquery.This is not enough to help

Comment: I have done only upto this. Iam not getting any other ideas. Iam new to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
$('input:text').click(function () {
    if ($('#menu').is(':visible')) {
        $('input:text').attr('placeholder', 'Search');
        $('#menu').slideUp(1000);
        $('#dropdownhide').slideDown(500);
    } else {
        $('#dropdownhide').slideDown(500);
    }
});
$('#dropdownhide li').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).find('a span').text() == 'Bangalore') {
        $('input:text').attr('placeholder', 'Bangalore');
        $('#dropdownhide').slideUp(500);
        $('#menu').slideDown(1000);
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7M8xL/4/)

Comment: I want it as , as soon as i click on bangalore,the dropdown should come with placeholder as banagalore.

Comment: This hides first dropdown and changes placeholder to bangalore, and onclick of placeholder dropdown comes. I want the second dropdown to be displayed as soon as i click bangalore.

Comment: Thanks Sridhar. This was useful to me.

Comment: Actually i want something like this in this site http://www.zomato.com/ , Onclick of search button, one dropdown comes,and onclick of something there in dropdown, other dropdown appears.I want it like if i click on one value from first dropdown,the second dropdown should appear.